# How to implement Call Recording to work with Twilio Call Forwarding Function

Tags: twilio, call-recording

I have setup a twilio number and call forwarding to work with my Google Analytics. I was using Google Dynamics Forwarding numbers but they where not connecting to my VoIP provider.

I have set-up the following two functions, how can I integrate that with twilio's call recording?

**Function 1: callforward**

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let phoneNumber = event.PhoneNumber; 
    let campaign = event.campaign;
    let trackingId = event.trackingId;
    let domain = context.DOMAIN_NAME;
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    let allowedThrough = true;
//Checking campaign is given or not. If there is no campaign_name the call is not forwarding to another number
    if (campaign === null) {
        allowedThrough = false;
    }
    let dialParams = {};
    if (campaign) {
        dialParams.campaign = campaign;
    }

var actionUrl ='https://'+domain+'/call_action?PhoneNumber='+phoneNumber+'&campaign='+campaign+'&trackingId='+trackingId;

    if (allowedThrough) {
        twiml.dial(
           {
           action :encodeURI(actionUrl),
           method:'GET'
           },phoneNumber
        );
    }
    else {
        twiml.say('Sorry, you are calling from a restricted number. Goodbye.');
    }
// return the TwiML
    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

**Function 2: call_action**

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
var http = require('http'); 
const analyticsID  = event.trackingId; 
const gaUrl = "http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid="+analyticsID+"&";
function sendAnalyticsEvent(eventParams,callback) {
   var url = gaUrl+eventParams;
   http.get(url, function(res) {
       if(res.statusCode === 200){
            console.log("Sent event: status="+res.statusCode+", params", eventParams);
            let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
            twiml.hangup();
            callback(null, twiml);
       }
   }).on('error', function(e) {
       console.log("Sent event: error="+e.message+", params", eventParams);
       let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
       twiml.say('Sorry, there is an error in reporting analyitics. Good bye.');
       callback(null, twiml);
   });
}
    var callerGeoDetail = GeoCode(event.From);
    var callerGeoCode   = callerGeoDetail["code"];
    var contact = event.From;
    var Duration = event.DialCallDuration;
    var CallStatus = event.DialCallStatus;
    if(Duration === undefined){ Duration=0;}
    var eventParams = "ec=Call&ea="+CallStatus+"&ev="+Duration+"&el="+event.campaign+"&t=event&amp;v=1&cid="+contact;
    eventParams += "&geoid="+callerGeoCode;
    sendAnalyticsEvent(eventParams,callback);
};
function GeoCode(number) {
    var _4DigitgeoCodeMapping = get4DigitGeoCodeMapping();
    var _3DigitgeoCodeMapping = get3DigitGeoCodeMapping();
    var _2DigitgeoCodeMapping = get2DigitGeoCodeMapping();
    var _1DigitgeoCodeMapping = get1DigitGeoCodeMapping();
    var get4DigitCallingCode  = number.substring(1, 5);
    var get3DigitCallingCode  = number.substring(1, 4);
    var get2DigitCallingCode  = number.substring(1, 3);
    var get1DigitCallingCode  = number.substring(1, 2);
    var geoCode = _4DigitgeoCodeMapping[get4DigitCallingCode] || _3DigitgeoCodeMapping[get3DigitCallingCode] || _2DigitgeoCodeMapping[get2DigitCallingCode] || _1DigitgeoCodeMapping[get1DigitCallingCode] || "2270";
    console.log("geoCode",geoCode);
    if(geoCode == "20117") // mapping of area code for US or Canadian number.
    {
        var areaCodeToGeoCodeMapping = getAreaCodeToGeoCodeMapping();
        var areaCode    = number.substring(2, 5);
        var geoAreaCode     = areaCodeToGeoCodeMapping[areaCode] || "20117";
        var geoAreaDetails  = {"code": geoAreaCode};
        console.log("geoDetails",geoAreaDetails);
        return geoAreaDetails;
    }
    else{
        var geoDetails = {"code": geoCode};
        console.log("geoDetails",geoDetails);
        return geoDetails;
    }
}

function get4DigitGeoCodeMapping(){
    return{
        "1473": "21137", "1671": "2316", "1876": "2388", "1664": "2500", "1670": "2580", "1787": "2630", "1939": "2630", "1869": "2659", "1758": "2662", "1784": "2670", "1868": "2780", "1649": "2796", "1284": "2850", "1340": "2850", "1684": "2882", "1264": "2660", "1268": "2028", "1242": "2044", "1246": "2052", "1441": "2060", "1345": "2136", "1767": "2212", "1809": "2212", "1828": "2212", "1849": "2212"
    };
}
function get3DigitGeoCodeMapping(){
    return{      
"355": "2008", "213": "2012", "376": "2020", "244": "2024", "374": "21519", "297": "2533", "994": "2031", "973": "2048", "880": "2050", "375": "2112", "501": "2084", "229": "2204", "975": "2064", "591": "2068", "387": "2070", "267": "2072", "673": "2096", "359": "2100", "226": "2854", "257": "2108", "855": "2116", "237": "2120", "238": "2132", "236": "2140", "235": "2148", "618": "2162", "269": "2174", "242": "2178", "243": "2180", "682": "2184", "506": "2188", "225": "2430", "385": "2191", "357": "2196", "420": "2203", "253": "2262", "593": "20264", "503": "2222", "240": "2226", "291": "2232", "372": "2233", "251": "2231", "500": "2238", "298": "2234", "679": "2242", "358": "2246", "594": "2254", "689": "2258", "241": "2266", "220": "2270", "995": "2268", "233": "2288", "350": "2292", "299": "2304", "590": "2312", "502": "2320", "224":"2324", "245":"2324", "592": "2328", "509": "2332", "379":"2336", "504":"2340", "852":"2344", "354":"2352", "964": "2368", "353": "2372", "972":"2376", "962":"2400", "254":"2404", "686":"2296", "850": "21331", "965": "2414", "996":"2417", "856":"2418", "371":"2428", "961":"2422", "266": "2426", "231": "2430", "218": "2434", "423": "2438", "370": "2440", "352": "2442", "853": "2446", "389": "2807", "261": "2450", "265": "2454", "960": "2462", "223": "2466", "356": "2470", "692": "2584", "596": "2474", "222": "2478", "230": "2480", "262": "2175", "691": "2583", "373": "2498", "377": "2492", "976": "20167", "382": "2499", "212": "2504", "258": "2508", "264": "2516", "674":"2520", "977": "2524", "599": "2530", "687": "2540", "505": "2558", "227": "2562", "234": "2566", "683": "2570", "672": "2574", "968": "2512", "680": "2585", "970": "2376", "507": "21142", "675": "2598", "595": "2600", "870": "2612", "351": "2620", "974": "2634", "250": "2646", "290": "2682", "508": "2666", "685": "2882", "378": "21137", "239": "2678", "966": "2682", "221": "2686", "381": "2688", "248": "2690", "232": "2694", "421": "2703", "386": "2705", "677": "2090", "252": "2706", "249": "21176", "597": "2740", "268": "2748", "963": "2368", "886": "2158", "992": "2762", "255": "2834", "670": "2626", "228": "2768", "690": "2772", "676": "2776", "216":"2788", "993": "2795", "688": "2798", "256": "2800", "380": "2804", "971": "2784", "598": "2858", "998": "2860", "678": "2548", "681": "2876", "967": "2887", "260": "2894", "263": "2716"
    };
}

function get2DigitGeoCodeMapping(){
    return{                                     
"93": "2004", "54": "20008", "61": "20035", "43": "20048", "32": "2056", "55": "20088", "57": "20114", "53": "21147", "45": "21154", "20": "21164", "33": "20332", "49": "20235", "30": "2300", "36": "2348", "91": "2356", "62": "2360", "98": "2368", "81": "20624", "76": "2398", "77": "2398", "82": "21331", "60": "20737", "52": "21142", "31": "2528", "64": "2554", "92": "2586", "51": "2604", "63": "2608", "48": "20862", "40": "21244", "65": "2702", "27": "21222", "34": "20282", "94": "2144", "47": "2744", "46": "21014", "41": "20133", "66": "21044", "90": "21354", "44": "20339", "58": "21204", "84": "21044"    
    };
}
function get1DigitGeoCodeMapping(){
    return{
        "1":"20117","7":"20931"
    };
}

function getAreaCodeToGeoCodeMapping() {
    return {
        "907": "21132", "205": "21133", "251": "21133", "256": "21133", "334": "21133", "479": "21135", "501": "21135", "870": "21135", "480": "21136", "520": "21136", "602": "21136", "623": "21136", "928": "21136", "209": "21137", "213": "21137", "310": "21137", "323": "21137", "408": "21137", "415": "21137", "424": "21137", "510": "21137", "530": "21137", "559": "21137", "562": "21137", "619": "21137", "626": "21137", "650": "21137", "661": "21137", "707": "21137", "714": "21137", "760": "21137", "805": "21137", "818": "21137", "831": "21137", "858": "21137", "909": "21137", "916": "21137", "925": "21137", "949": "21137", "303": "21138", "719": "21138", "720": "21138", "970": "21138", "203": "21139", "475": "21139", "860": "21139", "959": "21139", "202": "21140", "302": "21141", "239": "21142", "305": "21142", "321": "21142", "352": "21142", "386": "21142", "407": "21142", "561": "21142", "727": "21142", "754": "21142", "772": "21142", "786": "21142", "813": "21142", "850": "21142", "863": "21142", "904": "21142", "941": "21142", "954": "21142", "229": "21143", "404": "21143", "470": "21143", "478": "21143", "678": "21143", "706": "21143", "770": "21143", "912": "21143", "808": "21144", "319": "21145", "515": "21145", "563": "21145", "641": "21145", "712": "21145", "208": "21146", "217": "21147", "224": "21147", "309": "21147", "312": "21147", "331": "21147", "464": "21147", "618": "21147", "630": "21147", "708": "21147", "773": "21147", "815": "21147", "847": "21147", "872": "21147", "219": "21148", "260": "21148", "317": "21148", "574": "21148", "765": "21148", "812": "21148", "316": "21149", "620": "21149", "785": "21149", "913": "21149", "270": "21150", "502": "21150", "606": "21150", "859": "21150", "225": "21151", "318": "21151", "337": "21151", "504": "21151", "985": "21151", "339": "21152", "351": "21152", "413": "21152", "508": "21152", "617": "21152", "774": "21152","781": "21152", "857": "21152", "978": "21152", "227": "21153", "240": "21153", "301": "21153", "410": "21153", "443": "21153", "667": "21153", "207": "21154", "231": "21155", "248": "21155", "269": "21155", "313": "21155", "517": "21155", "586": "21155", "616": "21155", "734": "21155", "810": "21155", "906": "21155", "947": "21155","989": "21155", "218": "21156", "320": "21156", "507": "21156", "612": "21156", "651": "21156", "763": "21156", "952": "21156", "314": "21157", "417": "21157", "557": "21157", "573": "21157", "636": "21157", "660": "21157", "816": "21157", "975": "21157", "228": "21158", "601": "21158", "662": "21158", "406": "21159", "252": "21160", "336": "21160", "704": "21160", "828": "21160", "910": "21160", "919": "21160", "980": "21160", "984": "21160", "701": "21161", "308": "21162", "402": "21162", "603": "21163", "201": "21164", "551": "21164", "609": "21164", "732": "21164", "848": "21164", "856": "21164", "862": "21164", "908": "21164", "973": "21164", "505": "21165", "702": "21166", "775": "21166", "212": "21167", "315": "21167", "347": "21167", "516": "21167", "518": "21167", "585": "21167", "607": "21167", "631": "21167", "646": "21167", "716": "21167", "718": "21167", "845": "21167", "914": "21167", "917": "21167", "216": "21168", "234": "21168", "283": "21168", "330": "21168", "419": "21168", "440": "21168", "513": "21168", "567": "21168", "614": "21168", "740": "21168", "937": "21168", "405": "21169", "580": "21169", "918": "21169", "503": "21170", "541": "21170", "971": "21170", "215": "21171", "267": "21171", "412": "21171", "445": "21171", "484": "21171", "570": "21171", "610": "21171", "717": "21171", "724": "21171", "814": "21171", "835": "21171", "878": "21171", "401": "21172", "803": "21173", "843": "21173", "864": "21173", "605": "21174", "423": "21175", "615": "21175", "731": "21175", "865": "21175", "901": "21175", "931": "21175", "210": "21176", "214": "21176", "254": "21176", "281": "21176", "361": "21176", "409": "21176", "469": "21176", "512": "21176", "682": "21176", "713": "21176", "737": "21176", "806": "21176", "817": "21176", "830": "21176", "832": "21176", "903": "21176", "915": "21176", "936": "21176", "940": "21176", "956": "21176", "972": "21176", "979": "21176", "435": "21177", "801": "21177", "276": "21178", "434": "21178", "540": "21178", "571": "21178", "703": "21178", "757": "21178", "804": "21178", "802": "21179", "206": "21180", "253": "21180", "360": "21180", "425": "21180", "509": "21180", "564": "21180", "262": "21182", "414": "21182", "608": "21182", "715": "21182", "920": "21182", "304": "21183", "307": "21184"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Record attribute of the Dial verb to record the call.

```
if (allowedThrough) {
    twiml.dial(
       {
       action :encodeURI(actionUrl),
       method:'GET',
       record: 'record-from-ringing'
       },phoneNumber
    );
}
```

[record Attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#record)